# how to validate session on react client after successful authentication from express session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, react-router

I have setup an express REST API backend , React Front End . When user launches front end app , it will be redirecting user to signin page using oauth and express server creates session id after successful authentication. I could see a browser cookie connect.sid.

In my react app i have a private route which i defined to check user is not logged in or not before dashboard or user profile page. But i am not sure what check i can do to validate user session.

```
<Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
<Route path='/login' component={Login} />
<Route path='/register' component={Register} />
<PrivateRoute authed={this.props.isSessionActive} path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
<PrivateRoute authed={this.props.isSessionActive} path='/user-profile' component={UserProfile} />
```

One solution i can think of is calling in my redux action e.g. isSessionActive call express REST API and check for req.isAuthenticate() on REST API middleware. I am not sure if calling the API before each page navigation is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cookie with the session id is readable, you can just read the cookie from your react app and if there is a session id, you know the user is logged in.

If you cannot read the cookie because it's HttpOnly, you would have to make an endpoint that lets you check if there is a session, and if there is a valid session, return some information about the user. Then you can store that user data in a global state.

Example:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const sid = Cookies.get('session') || ''
if(sid){
   this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
}
```

If your cookie is HttpOnly:

Lets say you're using express.

```
app.get('/session/', (req, res) => {
   const token = req.cookies.session || ''
   if(token){
      ... perform some operation to get user data based on reading the token
      res.status(200).send({user})
   else{
      res.status(200).send({message: 'No valid session'})
   }
})
```

I choose to send 200 regardless, because the request is read successfully, we just don't have an active session.

});

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention but it is httpOnly cookie.

Comment: Okay, ive provided a solution if its an httponly cookie

Comment: so as long as my redux store has this user session data (ideally we get this after firstsuccessfull authentication.) , i can avoid making API call to check session is active or not , am i right ? And if i am not wrong the only time i would call /session api call is to check session active or not when page is refreshed and store has lost its in memory data. And use global state first to check user session before all page navigations and then call /session end point if redux doesn't have user session object.

Comment: Yes exactly. You only make this api call when you the user first enters the sites, or refreshes his / her browser. Storing the user data you need in global state allows you to keep it in memory. You can actually see this in action by going to airbnb.com website. You'll see they have no user data state in localstorage or sessionstorage, and if you refresh, look at their navbar. The navbar shows 2 states: initial state, and quickly changes to user state, because they are also making api calls for user data.